# How to set <xsd:minInclusive> decimal value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd.exe

I want to set `minInclusive` to 0.01.   I have tried below one but failed.

```
<xs:simpleType name="WeightType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:totalDigits value="5"/>
        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
        <xs:minInclusive value="0.01"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Can anyone please suggest how to write it?

If it is not possible, is there any other approach to achieve it?
My requirement is field should be greater than 0.

Comment: Please show a complete XML Schema document and explain what "but failed" means. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I have validations on it.
when <xs:minInclusive value="1"/> if we give value 0 , it throws validations.
my requirement is if value lessthan or equal to 0 , i need to throw validation.

Comment: What does "I have validations on it" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to allow values equal to 0.01 or greater, your `xs:simpleType` is fine as defined.

However, if your true requirement is to restrict the value to be greater than zero, rather than

```
  <xs:minInclusive value="0.01"/>
```

you can simply use

```
  <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
```

---

Since you're still having trouble, let's be very complete and thorough...

**This XSD,**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="w" type="WeightType"/>

  <xs:simpleType name="WeightType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:totalDigits value="5"/>
      <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
      <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

**will not** validate these XML instances,

```
<w>-0.1</w>
<w>0</w>
```

but **will** validate these XML instances:

```
<w>1</w>
<w>0.1</w>
<w>0.01</w>
```